# Customize Monaco Editor's context-menu (display it externally to the editor)

Tags: monaco-editor

Does anyone know if it is possible to customize the context menu in Monaco Editor?

The problem is that I am using the Monaco Editor in an integrated browser control inside classic Desktop application. When Monaco Editor displays a context menu, it becomes naturally truncated by the browser control window borders.

The question is: is it possible to get the list of items to be displayed to show the context menu externally (via classic Win32 menu, for example) and then propagate the chosen action back to the editor.